# How to insert data into fusion table using php?

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables

I am using fusion tables to generate pins over the map. Now I want to insert more coordinates data into the table using PHP but couldn't get any exact idea how to do it?

Can anyone help me for that?

Comment: Theres always the fusion tables API:  https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/

Comment: I am succeeded to get data from the table by API but can't figure out how to insert data from an api so can you please help me on that?

Comment: That's much more complicated as you have to go through the whole user authentication process.  That turned me off to fusion tables so I developed using mySQL w/PHP instead.  If you've worked with the API already, they do have a portion for insert statements in the help files.   I've never worked with it directly, sorry I can't help any more beyond that: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Inserting

Comment: Okay; Never mind; By the way thanks for your support Roy :)